Jasypt Decryption Failure During Jenkins Pipeline Deployment
pipeline {
    agent any

    tools {
        gradle 'Gradle'
    }

    environment {
        JASYPT_PASSWORD = credentials('jasypt-password-id') 
        SERVER_IP = '***.***.***.***'
        DEPLOY_PATH = '/root'
        JAR_FILE = 'build/libs/bobzip-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar'
    }

    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
            steps {
                git url: 'https://github.com/Firedrago95/project_bobzip', branch: 'main'
            }
        }

        stage('Prepare') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh 'chmod +x ./gradlew'
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh "./gradlew clean build -x test -Pjasypt.encryptor.password=${JASYPT_PASSWORD}"
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def runAppCommand = "java -Dspring.profiles.active=prod -Djasypt.encryptor.password=${JASYPT_PASSWORD} -jar $DEPLOY_PATH/bobzip-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"
                    
                    sh "scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $JAR_FILE root@$SERVER_IP:$DEPLOY_PATH/"
        
                    sshagent(['deploy_ssh_key']) {
                        sh """
                        ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$SERVER_IP '
                            $runAppCommand'
                        """
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    post {
        success {
            echo 'Deployment was successful.'   
        }
        failure {
            echo 'Deployment failed'
        }
    }  

The Jenkins Pipeline code is as shown above. The build succeeds, but an error occurs during runtime. The error code is as follows:
enter image description here
@Configuration
public class JasyptConfig {

    private final Environment env;

    public JasyptConfig(Environment env) {
        this.env = env;
    }

    @Bean(name = "jasyptStringEncryptor")
    public StringEncryptor jasyptStringEncryptor() {

        PooledPBEStringEncryptor encryptor = new PooledPBEStringEncryptor();
        SimpleStringPBEConfig config = new SimpleStringPBEConfig();

        // 시스템 속성에서 암호화 비밀번호를 가져옵니다.
        String encryptKey = env.getProperty("jasypt.encryptor.password");

        config.setPassword(encryptKey); // 암호키가 필요한 method -> 암호키 필드를 값으로 전달
        config.setAlgorithm("PBEWithMD5AndDES"); // 처리에 필요한 알고리즘
        config.setKeyObtentionIterations("1000");
        config.setPoolSize("1");
        config.setProviderName("SunJCE");
        config.setSaltGeneratorClassName("org.jasypt.salt.RandomSaltGenerator");
        config.setIvGeneratorClassName("org.jasypt.iv.NoIvGenerator");
        config.setStringOutputType("base64");
        encryptor.setConfig(config);
        return encryptor;
    }
}

This is my first time using Jenkins, so I’m not sure how to resolve the issue. and I will also include the code for decryption.

Please [edit] your question and paste the logs directly to the text instead of linking an image.
